# How to pass Json as input to rest web services in java

Tags: java

[image]
Sending input from postman for web service

[image]
At the @consume I have given type as application/json but 415 error is returning in postman.

Comment: Post your Student class @user

Comment: and i can see "age":"23", is age is String type? @user

Comment: Age is integer data type

Comment: Then why you are sending in string format? "age":23 send like this @Aswanthkishore

Answer (score 0):

Please add headers in your Postman request before sending the request.

```
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
```

Since you have used both the annotations i.e. @Produces and @Consumes hence you need to send both the headers.

Comment: sry ,after adding the same you have suggested it remains same .Can you suggest any other ways to correct